# Symbol not found in header file

Tags: c, header

I have this c program:

```
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    "ourhdr.h"

int     glob = 6;       /* external variable in initialized data */
char    buf[] = "a write to stdout\n";

int
main(void)
{
    int     var;        /* automatic variable on the stack */
    pid_t   pid;

    var = 88;
    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf)-1) != sizeof(buf)-1)
        err_sys("write error");
    printf("before fork\n");    /* we don't flush stdout */

    if ( (pid = fork()) < 0)
        err_sys("fork error");
    else if (pid == 0) {        /* child */
        glob++;                 /* modify variables */
        var++;
    } else
        sleep(2);               /* parent */

    printf("pid = %d, glob = %d, var = %d\n", getpid(), glob, var);
    exit(0);
}
```

In the header file "ourhdr.h" (located in the same folder) i defined several functions, such as err_sys().
I get this error while compiling with gcc:

```
In function "main":
undefined reference to "err_sys"
```

How can i get this working? I can post the header file here if needed. Thank you.

** EDIT: ** This is the ourhdr.h file: http://pastebin.com/fMUiG4zU

Comment: Where did you define `err_sys()` ?

Comment: "undefined reference" is a linker error. You need to link with the library/object file containing the symbol.

Comment: make sure the file having definition of 'err_sys' is getting build.

Comment: @DanielFischer how can i do that? the file containing the symbol is ourhdr.h, err_sys is defined in that file.

Comment: @AntonioFalcone It might be declared but not defined. There's a difference. Where is the function body ? It should be in a file you build alongside your main file.

Comment: @AntonioFalcone `void err_sys(const char *, ...);` as seen in `ourhdr.h` file is called declaration. This function should be defined somewhere in other file, possibly not in `ourhdr.h`. Use that file while compiling

Comment: If only we could just write `int main(int argc, char** argv);` in a header file and then include that, and our programs would magically manifest themselves and do what we want them to do. Alas, we actually have to write the code, but no code for `err_sys` is apparent. You got "ourhdr.h" from somewhere; you need to get the source that goes with it, or the compiled library, too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For me, it is compiling and working fine if you write the function name is written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have included the header file with the declaration of `err_sys`. Ensure you have also an implementation that is passed to the linker. Background:

The compiler compiles a module to an object file:
`g++ -c modul1.c` generates `modul1.o`
`g++ -c modul2.c` generates `modul2.o`

Each of the modules can reference functions that are defined in a included header file. Up to here, no actual implementation of that function is needed.

In the next step, the linker links toghether all object files (and libraries):
`g++ modul1.o modul2.o` generates `./a.out` or similar

In the second step, an implementation for all used functions is needed. Be sure you provided it!

(P.S.: Some compilers allow compiling and linking with one command, if you have multiple modules you can perhaps add them to a single gcc-call. I'd recomment to use make though)

Answer (score 0):

I think what's likely to happen is that you have a header, *ourhdr.h*, containing the definition of the function, but the implementation is in a different file: *ourhdr.c*. In that case, if you try to compile without including *ourhdr.c* you'll get a reference error:

```sh
$ gcc main.c
/bin/ld: /tmp/ccVzNF6w.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `err_sys'
```

To fix it, you need to compile like this:

```sh
$ gcc main.c ourhdr.c
```

Another option is to define the body of the function in *ourhdr.h*:

```
// ourhdr.h

#include <stdio.h>

void err_sys(const char* str);

void err_sys(const char* str) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", str);
}
```

In that case, `gcc main.c` should work.